# Visual Studio 2008 - speed up Add Reference

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there *any* way to speed up the Add Reference dialog? For example, has anyone found any way to open it by default in the Recent or Browse tabs (which is what I use 90% of the time), to avoid the other tabs' slowness?

All I have found is [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2009/05/14/visual-studio-working-on-performance.aspx) where a lot of people complain about this issue, but no solutions...

Note that this is not a duplicate of [8440](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations) as this is not a general question.

Comment: I don't think that you'll find an answer. If it's really annoying for you you can always edit csproj/vbproj manually ;)

Comment: Agreed it's not going to get fixed.  Presumably, since it's scanning the GAC, you could make efforts to thin its contents down to the bare minimum, but that's sort of self-defeating.

Comment: OMG I feel your pain, the worst is to get into a coding groove and then click "Add Reference" and ... all ... productivity ... halts ...

Comment: Upgrade to Visual Studio 2010...

Comment: @SLC: take a look at the date of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't believe there is a good way to speed it up.

However, you can try a plug-in that does similar a thing but faster:

- [Fast Add Reference Dialog](http://devlicio.us/blogs/tuna_toksoz/archive/2009/06/18/vs-addin-fast-add-reference-dialog-no-more-coffee-break.aspx)
- [CR_QuickAddReference](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/CR_QuickAddReference)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this is possible, or that it's going to get fixed by Microsoft - see this item on
[Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=114374) ...

Answer (score 2):

I replaced my HD with an SSD. Now opening the Add References dialog takes about 2 seconds when I open it the first time, less than a second after that. That alone was worth the money.

Answer (score 1):

Try tweaking your virus checker.

I keep my virus checker (Nod32) set to scan on write, create, execute but not "file read".  My whole machine is about 3 times faster, and "add reference" takes under 3 seconds.  If I have my virus checker scanning reads it takes about 15 seconds to load add reference!!!  Of course this introduces a small amount of risk, but for me the performance improvements far outweigh the risks.

Comment: Wow - my machine uses raid0 raptors for system storage, is decently speced with 4GB mem and a regular core 2 duo and so on and is extremely zippy normally, but the first invoke of the add reference dialog in VS 2008 thrashes through the disk like crazy and takes several seconds to show... the first time. And it blows ^^ (all subsequent invokes of add reference is of course immediate due to caching)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way of adding a reference is to use the following visual studio extensions

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/36a6eb45-a7b1-47c3-9e85-09f0aef6e879

Enjoy,

Muse VSExtensions

Answer (score 0):

<tongue mode="in cheek">
Get a faster machine?
</tongue>

Comment: +1 for funny, but really ... we're just browsing the GAC here. Why the slowness? (Not like I've ever written a program to browse and parse the GAC ... )

Answer (score 0):

[VS2010 fixes this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/29/add-reference-dialog-improvements-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx).